# How to use align environment when the math is too long

Tags: align

I want to use the `align` environment like so:

```
\begin{itemsize}
  \begin{align}
    {\color{purple} \mathcal{L} [f'(t)](s) = s \mathcal{L} [f(t)](s) - f(0) } \\
    {\color{red} \mathcal{L} [f^{(n)}(t)](s) = s^n \mathcal{L} [f(t)](s) - s^{n- 
1}f(0) - s^{n-2}f(0) - \dots - f^{n-1}(0)}
  \end{align}
  n mal differenzierbar:
\end{itemsize}
```

the output is such that the text line `"n mal differenzierbar:"`, that should be behind the second equation, is below it (I guess because of the length). So, I want to move it above the equation.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use a complete MWE that contains the ``\documentclass``, all the ``\usepackages`` (and libraries if you use ``tikz`` or something like that), as well as the ``\begin{document}`` and ``\end{document}``. Please refer to [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl) and to [this](http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html)

Comment: I assume you mean `itemize`. Also, `align` is designed to vertically align consecutive lines at a character marked with a `&` symbol. Your code doesn't have that. Please specify your desired output more clearly. And always include a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
{\color{purple} \mathcal{L} [f'(t)](s)\;} & {\color{purple}= s \mathcal{L} [f(t)](s) - f(0) } \\
\intertext{n mal differenzierbar:}
{\color{red} \mathcal{L} [f^{(n)}(t)](s)\;} & {\color{red}= s^n \mathcal{L} [f(t)](s) - s^{n- 1}f(0) - s^{n-2}f(0) - \dots - f^{n-1}(0)  }
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
n mal differenzierbar:
\begin{align}
{\color{purple} \mathcal{L} [f'(t)](s)\;} & {\color{purple}= s \mathcal{L} [f(t)](s) - f(0) } \\
{\color{red} \mathcal{L} [f^{(n)}(t)](s)\;} & {\color{red}= s^n \mathcal{L} [f(t)](s) - s^{n- 1}f(0) - s^{n-2}f(0) - \dots - f^{n-1}(0)  }
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]